# Phonegap with Android 4.0.4 and JQuery-mobile, overflow breaks click event

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova, overflow

I have a scrollable div using Phonegap with JQM and Android 4.0.4, but all items inside the scrollable div is not clickable anymore, it seems overflow breaks the click event, it works on newer android and iOS, but not on 4.0.4. If I remove the overflow, then I can click anyway to solve this?